# MySql, how to DELETE looped data

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I have this code and I need to DELETE the row where submit button was clicked

```
<fieldset id=''><form method='post' action='del_menu.php'>
                <?php

                    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obedy ORDER BY datum DESC");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

                        $time = strtotime( $row[0] );
                        $myDate = date( 'd.m.', $time );
                        $w_day = date( 'N', $time );
                        $ww_day = $w_day-1;

                        echo "<p>" . $myDate . "&emsp;";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='menu1' id='menu1' class='input' value='". $row[1] ."' size='37'/>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='menu2' id='menu2' class='input' value='". $row[2] ."' size='37'/>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='menu3' id='menu3' class='input' value='". $row[3] ."' size='37'/>";
                        echo "<input type='submit' formaction='del_menu.php' class='button' value='Smazat' />";
                        echo "</p>";

                        $the_row=" $row[0]";

                        }

                    mysql_free_result($result);

                ?>
                </form></fieldset>
```

How should I do that? Thanks for help

Comment: Check the `$_POST` array for passed `menu1`, `menu2` and `menu3` values, and delete accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key in your table and post that key in your form. Then use the key to delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input element to store the id (the primary key of the row, i.e., the key that is unique on that row so you can identify it). 
The code should look like this:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' class='input' value='". row['id_identifier'] . "' />";
```

At each submit you can check the POST variable, in this case $_POST['id']